# Not able to get the Windows User Name using 'User.Identity.Name' in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to use 'MsgBox(User.Identity.Name)' to show the Current Windows User in a MessageBox. The MessageBox that appears shows "App_Web_1gu0lxe5" as the Title and Message is Empty. In other words I am not able to get the Current Windows User in the Output.

I am using Windows 8.1 Enterprise, 64-bit Operating System, Microsoft Visual Studio 2012, Visual Basic is the Programming Language and I am trying to develop a Web Application.

When I am running the same code on a Machine running "Windows 7 Enterprise, Service Pack 1, 64-bit Operating System" the code produces the desired result.

Any Idea what could be the cause of the Problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363766/httpcontext-current-user-identity-name-is-empty-using-iis-express-but-not-visual

Comment: Why are you using `MsgBox` in an ASP.NET application? That's for Windows Forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably had Anonymous Authentication on as well as Windows Authentication. Turn off Anonymous off.

So,

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
</system.web>
```

In IIS config for the app, look in Authentication tab

Set **Anonymous Authentication** to **Disabled** and
Set **Windows Authentication** to **Enabled**

This should work and the Identity.UserName should now show up properly.